# sending email from flutter app is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send an email from my flutter app. When I run it in debug mode everything seems to work without any errors. However, I never receive an email.

This is the code I use to send the email:

```
Future sendNewUserEmail() async {
    final api = GoogleAuthApi();
    final googleUser = await api.signIn;
    const accessToken = '';

    final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2('myemail@gmail.com', accessToken);
    final message = Message()
      ..from = const Address("myemail@gmail.com", "Deal Diligence")
      ..recipients = ['recipient@gmail.com']
      ..subject = "Welcome to Deal Diligence"
      ..text = "Welcome to Deal Diligence. Your password is NewPassword";

    try {
      await send(message, smtpServer);

      //showSnackBar('Invitation email successfully sent');
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Here are the values held in the smtpServer variable:

```
allowInsecure:false
hashCode:403922433
host:"smtp.gmail.com"
ignoreBadCertificate:false
password:null
port:465
runtimeType:
Type (SmtpServer)
ssl:true
username:null
xoauth2Token:"dXNlcj1ua2FuZTEyMzRAZ21haWwuY29tAWF1dGg9QmVhcmVyIAEB"
```

I don't have a username or password so maybe that is the problem but the example I watched didn't set them either.

What is wrong here?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
Running through the debugger I realized that this line of code is not being executed but it is not throwing an error either.

```
final googleUser = await api.signIn;
```

I don't know why it would skip this line of code. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess (because I'm not into flutter/dart), but typically in other languages you call a method by `api.signIn()` (note the `()` in the end)